# Play YouTube video in VLC with subtitles (if available)

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, youtube, subtitles, media-player

I want to play youtube video such as [Authoritarianism: Last Week Tonight with John Oliver (HBO)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ximgPmJ9A5s) in VLC Player. As this video has subtitles, can I play it in VLC along with the subtitles?

Comment: SMPlayer can use VLC, but I'm not sure about the subtitles...